# Whilst shooting e-tech guns, the muzzle opens

Tags: borderlands-2

I noticed that when you fire e-tech guns, as you continue to unload, the muzzle opens up. Is this indication of anything? Added bonus perhaps? Or is it purely aesthetic design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is purely an aesthetic design from only those weapon.  It does not give any bonus to my knowledge.  ( all bonuses are stated on the gun's stats page & player stats page)